Unable to load js resource
I have migrated my application from Grails 3.x to 6.1.2. After few fixes I was able to make it run again. In production it runs in a tomcat (9) in a linux box, and everything works fine. I did not realize, though, that in my IDE (IntelliJ on mac with jvm 11) when I run it in debug something is wrong, pages are correctly rendered but I see js are not loaded correctly

Lots of 500 error, in my IDE console I have this error message for each 500:
2024-09-04 08:46:45.878 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graalvm.polyglot.Context
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3191)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1904)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.MethodInfo.get(MethodInfo.java:70)
    at java.desktop/com.sun.beans.introspect.ClassInfo.getMethods(ClassInfo.java:80)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1029)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:445)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:195)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.lambda$addProperties$8(MetaClassImpl.java:3429)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3429)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.reinitialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3411)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3404)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:273)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:258)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:987)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile.processedStream(AbstractAssetFile.groovy:180)
    at asset.pipeline.AbstractAssetFile.processedStream(AbstractAssetFile.groovy)
    at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor.fileContents(DirectiveProcessor.groovy:320)
    at asset.pipeline.DirectiveProcessor$fileContents$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at asset.pipeline.AssetPipeline.serveUncompiledAsset(AssetPipeline.groovy:67)
    at asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineFilter.doFilterInternal(AssetPipelineFilter.groovy:288)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

